# Autenticação Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Estou estudando a parte de autenticação do Laravel e me baseando na seguinte documentação [Laravel](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/master/authentication)

Segui todos os passos:

- Configurei o banco de dados
- Coloquei as rotas
- Coloquei as Views

Quando eu entro em: (http://MEU_DOMINIO/public/auth/register) ele abre o formulário para cadastrar novos usuários, mas quando eu clico em "Register"

Da o seguinte erro:

> Not Found The requested URL /auth/register was not found on this
>   server.

vi que isso está me redirecionando para: (http://MEU_DOMINIO/auth/register)

Tentei utilizar o helper `route(...)` mas como isso não estava na documentação oficial achei melhor perguntar pro aqui...

Alguém já seguiu esses passos e teve o mesmo problema? e tem a solução?

Comment: Você precisa postar parte do seu código para poder saber o que está ocorrendo, neste caso, creio que o seu arquivo de rotas é suficiente.

Comment: Eu não cheguei a postar o meu código aqui, pois esta igual a  documentação do Laravel, mas na próxima eu posto mesmo assim. vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para iniciar com o scaffold para autenticação do Laravel, rode o seguinte comando no console:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Com isso serão criadas views padrões para cadastro e login, e também um middleware para autenticação, junto com um grupo de rotas. Tudo que você tem que fazer é colocar as rotas protegidas dentro desse grupo.

*Exemplo:*

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home.home', ['nav' => "home"]);
});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'ProductController@getAll');
        Route::get('/ajax', 'ProductController@getAllAjax');
        Route::get('/stock/danger', 'ProductController@getStockDanger');
        Route::get('/ajax/{id}', 'ProductController@getOne');
        Route::post('/store', 'ProductController@store');
        Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'ProductController@deleteView');
        Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy');
        Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'ProductController@editView');
        Route::post('/update', 'ProductController@update');
        Route::post('/search', 'ProductController@search');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'ProductController@detail');
});
Route::auth();
```

Nesse caso a rota que redireciona para `/` está publica enquanto o grupo dentro do `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {});` exige autenticação. Essa que é feita a partir da tabela `users` criada pelo próprio Laravel.

Comment: Obrigado, a sua explicação funcionou corretamente, só fiquei com uma duvida... o meu arquivo routes.php ficou assim Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'); não sei como esta funcionando o /home por exemp

Comment: Funciona da seguinte maneira, tudo que estiver dentro do group em que vc utiliza o middleware auth vai exigir autenticação do usuário, e o que não estiver dentro dele pode ser acessado sem autenticar.

Comment: Mas para o laravel navegar entre as páginas eu não preciso ter todas as rotas mapeadas no meu arquivo routes.php?

Comment: Esses Route::group não tem no meu arquivo routes.php

Comment: abra o endereço do seu projeto no terminal de digite php artisan make:auth   vai gerar o que você precisa para autenticação automaticamente.

Comment: sim, eu já fiz isso que você falou e já funcionou ok! Mesmo tudo funcionando perfeitamente eu acho que o meu routes.php está diferente de como você falou que ele deveria ficar, por isso minha duvida. Rodando esse comando ai, como deveria ficar o routes.php?

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel está utilizando?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47076/discussion-between-felipe-paetzold-and-andersonsouza).